# Swift Types and Generics: can it really be that cumbersome?

Tags: swift, generics

Getting to grips with Swift these days, I've implemented a Dictionary< Type: Any > in Swift. It's all working fine, but the code looks very ugly to me. Should I blame it on the language's youth, or on my inexperience with it? Any insight much appreciated!

Step 1: make a Type wrapper which conforms to Hashable( because neither Any.Type nor AnyClass does )

```
class HashableType : Hashable
{
    let type : Any.Type

    //Piggybacking String's Hashable implementation
    var hashValue : Int
    {
        return toString( type ).hashValue
    }

    init( type : Any.Type )
    {
        self.type = type
    }

    init( instance: Any )
    {
        self.type = instance.dynamicType
    }
}

//Equatable implementation, wish it could be nested in the class declaration...
func ==( lhs: HashableType, rhs: HashableType )->Bool
{
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Step 2: Real World use case - registering default instances for types

```
final class DefaultInstances
{
    private static var __defaultInstances = [ HashableType: Any ]()

    class func registerDefaultInstance( instance: Any ) -> Bool
    {
        let hashableType = HashableType( instance: instance )

        if let defaultInstance = __defaultInstances[ hashableType ]
        {
            return false
        }

        __defaultInstances[ hashableType ] = instance

        return true
    }

    // T, T.Type and T.self can all coexist, not a contrived example.
    // T.Type:  the "cannot explicitly specialize a generic function" compile error is quite a shame here -
    // would be much cleaner in C# for example
    class func defaultInstance< T >( type: T.Type ) -> T?
    {
        return __defaultInstances[ HashableType( type: T.self ) ] as? T

        // could also work as
        // return __defaultInstances[ HashableType( type: type ) ] as? T
    }
}
```

Step 3: Test

```
func TestDefaultInstances()
{
    if DefaultInstances.registerDefaultInstance( Int( 2 ) ) == true
    {
        println( "did register default int." )
    }
    else
    {
        if let defaultInt = DefaultInstances.defaultInstance( Int )
        {
            println( "Already registered Int default instance: \(defaultInt)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't implement `==` using hash codes.  Hash codes aren't guaranteed to be unique.  It would be better to equate the strings themselves.  And if you must use strings to identify types, you can use `toString(type)` rather than `String(interpolationSegment: )`.

Comment: But generally speaking, this is all a pretty bad idea – you just do not need this kind of dynamic behavior – either you want full-on dynamic functionality, in which case use `@objc` types rather than reinventing a weaker equivalent, or you want the type safety and performance benefits of static types and generics.  Don't mix the two and end up with the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the input! You're right, hashValue isn't guaranteed to be unique, but in the lifespan of a single execution of an application, it should be. Anyway, why would a dictionary which uses Type as key be such a bad idea? Many use cases spring to mind, and it's certainly feasible without jumping through any hoops in c# for example.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve?  You haven’t actually shown a practical use case, just a way of using types to drive lookups.  To what end do you want to use this?  Chances are, this end can be achieved via compile-time (overloading functions) or run-time (overriding methods) polymorphism.

Comment: Got there whilst trying to genericize ( via a base class or a protocol ) the behaviour of manager singletons which require user authorization ( PhotosManager, LocationManager, etc... ). The idea was to define a template behaviour for returning the sharedInstance immediately only if authorization had been already granted, or via a closure if it hadn't. Of course, it would take little duplicate code and much less fuss to just get on with it, but as I'm learning Swift, seemed like a nice play ground for practising generics / protocols / closures / optionals...